# MYSQLi bind_result is returning null

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to output the variables that I get from the database in my query but nothing is being returned. Using MYSQLi prepared statements.

Please see code below:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM transactions WHERE order_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $order_id);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name);
$stmt->close();


// Output review live to page 
echo $first_name;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you cannot learn from the previous experience, there is no point in learning at all. You already posed (and given) the code that fetches data from DB. Why can't you write just by example that you already have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the line to fetch the result. `fetch()`.

Try that:

```
  $stmt->bind_result($first_name, $last_name);
  $stmt->fetch();  // ----- > you forget that line to fetch results.
  $stmt->close();
```